# I need to pull out data held in a table into a javascript chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a javascript pie chart which I need to fill the data from one of my tables, I have a `users` table which holds a field called `idUsers` which I have used for the session id.

I have a table called `modules` which holds the moduleID and the moduleName, and then I have a join table between the two, called `UserTakingModule`, this table has a field called checkPoint which basically holds a number (which refers to a page in a slideshow), so the user knows where they last were. I'm trying to use that `checkPoint` to fill my chart data up. So if a user has got to a certain point within a module, use that. However I can't get it to work, please can someone point out what I've done wrong, really struggling. At present, no data appears at all in the js pie chart.

[image: Snapshot of Tables in PhpMyAdmin]

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `userTakingModule` WHERE `idUsers` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";

    $result = $conn -> query($query);

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
          {
      $mod1=$row['checkPoint'];
//    $mod2=$row[''];
//    $mod3=$row[''];
//    $mod4=$row[''];
//    $mod5=$row[''];
//    $mod6=$row[''];
          }
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ctx = document.getElementById("my3Chart");
            var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Time Management", "Career Coach", "Stress & Wellbeing", "Note Taking", "Exam Prep", "Presentations"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [<?php echo $mod1?>, <?php echo $mod2?>, <?php echo $mod3?>, <?php echo $mod4?>, <?php echo $mod5?> ,<?php echo $mod6?>],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
            </script>
```

***UPDATE:*** The pie charts appear fine if I just hard code values under data tag in the chart, I think it's to do with the SQL query, I almost need to perhaps say, show me `checkPoint` of `ModuleID'x'` under this user that's logged in?

Comment: Start with an HTML file that works, then change the hardcoded data to PHP

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Hi @mplungjan it works in html if I just hard code the values 1 , 2, 3 etc in the pie chart under data but I think it's my php assigning the `checkPoint` incorrectly. As I guess I would have to say `checkPoint` for `moduleID'x'` ? I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `implode` like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `userTakingModule` WHERE `idUsers` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";

    $result = $conn -> query($query);
    $mod = Array();
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
    {
          $mod[]=$row['checkPoint'];

    }
    $data = implode(',',$mod);
?>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ctx = document.getElementById("my3Chart");
            var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Time Management", "Career Coach", "Stress & Wellbeing", "Note Taking", "Exam Prep", "Presentations"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [<?php echo $data?>],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: PLEASE tell me how on earth this worked??? Will the figures appearing in the bar chart match the order of the labels in the pie chart? i.e. how will I know the `TimeManagement` under the js chart will match the correct data in my php table for that module

Comment: If the label information can also be extracted from the same query, then you can use the same process for the labels.  That way you guarantee that every label corresponds with the correct value.

Comment: Oh my lord thank you so so so much, so because I selected ALL from the UserTakingModule it somehow knew the module names, or was it because in the js chart code I named them under `labels` and it somehow just matched that the the ModuleName in my tables?

Comment: It is because you named them under `labels`.  If the order you hard coded is the same order the query return the results then you are in luck.  Just be careful it is the correct order.  It will be safer to match each value with the correct label by creating an array of labels similar to what I did with the `checkPoint` column.

Comment: Hi @alanfcm I don't suppose you could help me with that, or would it just be at the top of the page saying `$mod1 = " Exams";` and then just call `$mod1` in the `labels`

Comment: You would have to modify your query, joining the `module` table to extract the `ModuleName` column.  Then you would do something like `$labels[]=$row['ModuleName'];` and then the `implode` and then replace the hardcoded values with that.